# How do I see what quest I haven't completed yet?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can't get the reset quests button to show up on my wizard, which means there is a quest I haven't completed yet.  However, when I go to game settings, it allows me to choose every quest in every act which kind of implies I've done them all.

The only resource I can find is the [Quest Aggregator](http://xinair.net/diablo3/), which says I haven't killed Belial yet, but I have, many times.  However the quest reset button just isn't there.

What am I missing?  How do I see which quest is still marked as incomplete?

Comment: Ouch.  It doesn't just jump you to whatever quest you're on, marking everything between as complete?  I can see how that cuts down on abuse, but this is somewhat obtuse.

Comment: @Frank nope, its really annoying, and despite the award winning level of writing*, I really don't want to suffer through all of the quests again.  *sarcasm for people who don't play d3

Comment: Did you try to do the full Belial quest, or just start halfway through it to get to Belial?

Comment: @Katustrawfic I did the full thing, all the way through till I was in act 3

Comment: You should have completed every stage of every quest, too. That Aggregator site does not seem to show that, so I think it's possible you have not finished some quest, thought have had started the next one... Or something. If you have a character who is able to reset quests, try skimming through quest steps on that character, and see if the wizard misses something. I'll post a full list later today.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some minor hints in-game:

1. If, on top of the list of the quests for any given act when trying to join a **public game**, you have e.g. "Act I - Any quest", that means you have completed all the quests in this act.
2. If on the list of the quests for any act you see a gap in numbering, it's clear that these are the quests you are missing. Start on the last quest before the gap, and play till  the first quest after the gap.
3. When selecting quests, you also can select a step of the quest, you have already done. Most quests have some easily distinguishable end-step. As your last resort you could check which of the quests is missing it. Tip: Look for steps named like "Return to [name]".

Using these I was always able to finally track down missing quests, but it is far from convenient.

Comment: thanks, that tip #1 confirmed it was in act 2 somewhere so I ran through that real quick and got it.

Comment: This would be the first thing i would do. but gg good answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a fairly common problem. The "Reset Quests" button requires you to have completed not only every single quest, but also every checkpoint as well. Since there is no indicator (ingame), which means you have to resort to external means such as the one you mentioned.

The alternative is to play through the acts again; since the site you mentioned calls the missing part in the Belial kill quest, you can of course also go to the end of the quest before and just complete all checkpoints within the Belial quest. If the quest aggregator is correct, you should then be able to reset.

There have been also a couple of blue posts on this topic. I will give you the ones a quick google search popped up; there are other sites that mention these as well, of course (like diablofans.com, ...).

http://diablo.somepage.com/blue/11913971402-how-to-reset-quests

Cheers.